SQL query LEFT JOIN two tables with WHERE clause for the second table's column
Table1: Id1, Phrase
Data:
  1   Hello
  2   Bye
  3   Thanks

Table2: Id2, Color, Shape
Data:
  1   Green     Square
  3   Yellow    Circle
  3   Blue      Square

The requirement for the query is to return ALL rows from Table1 left joined with Table2 where Shape = 'Square', i.e.
1   Hello   Green
2   Bye     NULL
3   Thanks  Blue

Query 1:
SELECT Id1, Phrase, Color
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Id2 = Id1

would return
1   Hello   Green
2   Bye     NULL
3   Thanks  Yellow
3   Thanks  Blue

Query 2:
SELECT Id1, Phrase, Color
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Id2 = Id1
WHERE Shape = 'Square'

would return
1   Hello   Green
3   Thanks  Blue

How can I return what's required?

No, if you read carefully, query 1 is the same as query 2 but without a WHERE clause. They both return NOT what is required. One has too many rows, another one has too few (missing the row with the NULL).

This question is similar to: Left Join With Where Clause. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

"ALL rows from Table1 left joined with Table2 where Shape = 'Square'" is not clear. Eg it poorly describes both your queries. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. PS Is there any rule of thumb to construct SQL query from a human-readable description?

Your second query is almost correct, but the restriction in the WHERE clause needs to be moved to the ON clause of the join:
SELECT t1.Id1, t1.Phrase, t1.Color
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t2.Id2 = t1.Id1 AND
       t2.Shape = 'Square';

But phrasing the query this way, no rows from the first table are filtered off, even if there be no matching records in the second table.  Your current second query completely filters off any records not matching the shape requirement.

Another way to achieve this particular data-result is to add where Shape = 'Square' Or Shape is null.

Aha, of course! Thank you

@T.S. That assumes the column Shape is NOT NULL. It won't work otherwise.

@TheImpaler Yea, I said - for this particular set. also, I could use t2.Id2 is null
